# Anomaly detection with one-class SVM

Tags: svm, model

As I understood from my experimentation on some multivariate data-sets, anomaly detection (AD) heavily depends on the underlying distribution of data. Like, for ex., you can devise a method to detect anomalies supposing a Gaussian distribution for your data, and then end up with a failure if it is actually a power-law...

Then a visual investigation followed by a "fit a model" approach seems to be the best way for AD.

And I started to think that ML algorithms like one-class SVM is useless in most situations for AD.

So here is my silly and novice question: "Suppose you have a data-set with many variables (IDs) distributed in many ways (some gaussian, some power-law). How one can use a one-class SVM approach in this situation without taking care of distributions"?

Or do I need to study SVMs in more detail?

Comment: A one-class SVM with Gaussian kernel (for example) generally works well even if the data is not normally distributed. Typically, these are not the issues that cause a lot of headaches.

Comment: The question, as formulated, is un-answerable: what is meant by "without taking care of distributions" and what is meant by "How"--a link to a library?

Answer (score 2):

When using the SVM for novelty detection the actual distribution of data does not matter. WHat the algorithm [actually](http://axiom.anu.edu.au/~williams/papers/P126.pdf) does, is to estimate the [support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of the distribution from which the data is sampled, i.e. those regions of the feature space for which $p(x) > 0$. You can use it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the log of a variable with a distribution that follows a power-law will often do a pretty good job of making it more gaussian.  This would definitely be the first thing to try, and by itself will likely give you satisfactory results. In my limited experience, RBF kernels seem pretty robust, even if they are based on the Gaussian distribution.

If simply logging doesn't work, using domain-specific knowledge to focus on a subset of variables can also be helpful.

You could also use PCA or autoencoding to reduce the number of variables, although the distortion of the data might potentially not be worth it.